# Netty TCP Socket Overhead

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, netty

I'm a starter with Netty, and my aim is to send data objects through TCP sockets; but I have many number of data objects and I want to send using POJO like [shown here](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/guide/html/start.html#start.pojo).

However, the issue is that, I need to convert all my objects to byte arrays and **"only send these byte arrays with TCP overhead"** over the network. Considering this, my question is that is Netty will add overhead to my byte array or just encoded byte arrays + TCP overhead will be sent over Netty TCP sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netty doesn't add any protocol of its own. It just sends the bytes you send.

It wouldn't be much use otherwise.

Comment: Is there any official support/document about this topic, or any mention about it? Thank you for the answer btw.